# How do I resolve app crashing error while getting Location on android?

Tags: java, android, location, crash

Here is my complete code that I wrote. The code is intended to get the location of the device then a button is pressed. There are 2 text fields where the Latitude and longitude would be displayed.
Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.shankhanilghosh.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final TextView tLat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude),
            tLong=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitude);

    LocationManager locM;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final LocationListener l=new MyLocationListener();
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) throws SecurityException
            {
                locM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30000,50,l);
                Location loc=locM.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
        });
    }
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            tLat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            tLong.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }
}
```

I have also added the necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file. Here is the permissions page

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I am using android studio. Whenever I am building the code,and executing the APK, the app crashes. Please mention what is causing my code to crash, and how am I to resolve it.

Here is the logcat.

```
01-19 07:52:24.042 21131-21131/com.example.shankhanilghosh.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.shankhanilghosh.test, PID: 21131
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.shankhanilghosh.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: If its a crash post the logcat.  It tells you why it crashed.

Comment: Although I can tell you that you can't use findViewById before calling setContentView, so it will have failures doing it where you declare the views at class scope.  You also need to add runtime permissions checks.

Comment: alright @GabeSechan let me give it a try and re position it.

Comment: Earlier the app crashed the moment the activity is launched. But now, when I tap the button it crashed. And this is what it showed in RED in the logcat. 

01-19 07:51:51.729 21131-21131/com.example.shankhanilghosh.test E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not initialized your LocationManager
Add this line before button  OnClickListner

```
locM=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```